# Where can I find good research proposals of researches in computer science?

Tags: publications, computer-science, methodology, research-proposal

Where can I find good research proposals of researches in computer science? I specifically need to see some example methodology sections. I am writing a research proposal where the research problem is based on database systems and reinforcement learning. Writing the methodology section has become a great difficulty so far because there isn't any proper guidance or understanding I have on the area of academic documentation. If you can suggests a good book or a website to refer it's also helpful in this matter.

Comment: Why not read papers rather than proposals? Certainly you need to read them anyways to motivate your work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check with your local/national funding, research promotion, or research training agencies, as these may offer limited access to past proposals under some circumstances.  For example, the [Austrian Research Promotion Agency](http://www.ffg.at/en) maintains a reference library of successful ERC proposals that can be consulted by the public (albeit in person only, and without borrowing rights).  Similarly, the [Austrian Science Fund](https://www.fwf.ac.at/en/) and [Tutech Innovation](https://tutech.de/en/) periodically organize grant-writing workshops where real-life successful and unsuccessful grant applications are presented and analyzed for educational purposes.  For these two institutions, though, there's no guarantee that the proposals you'll be studying will be from your own field, and you can't take the proposals with you when you leave the workshop.

Another option may be to ask your current and past colleagues and supervisors if they will share their past proposals with you.  I've obtained a number of proposals this way, with the only restriction being that I had to keep them confidential.

Comment: informative and helpful. thanks